# Packages from OS or from custom package manager

Tags: package-management

Several programming languages have their own package manager for libraries. Ruby has gem, Haskell has cabal etc. But very often, some of the important libraries have an OS package as well. So which one should be chosen in which case? (apart from obvious cases, e.g. one doesn't work or is an old version that doesn't have a feature I need.) What are the advantages of those options? What are the best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose the package provided by your distribution/operating system.

Because if you do that, then your package-manager will know that these libraries are installed. (They usually don't check if the libraries exist only if the package with the libraries is installed.)

And if you try to install another package which depends on those libraries, you either

- have to tell you package manager somehow that the libraries are already installed (for example by creating a pseudopackage for them)

or

- the package manager will install the packages with the libraries and you will have two versions of those libraries on your system.